# Converting const reference of parent class into a derived child object

Tags: c++, visual-studio, pointers, memory

I have many events in my program that all inherit from `Entity`. I am struggling to figure out how to convert this back to one of the children such as `MouseMovedEvent`. `Entity` is passed around as
`const Entity& e` and I need some way to access the getters in MouseMovedEvent. I was thinking I could just cast `Entity` to `MouseMovedEvent` but I have tried like 6 different ways to effect.

Worst case scenario I was thinking of making the parameter for Event into `const Event* e` and then doing

`const MouseMovedEvent* childEvent = static_cast<const MouseMovedEvent*>(e);`

and this would work but I am worried that throwing around pointers could get a bit messy. I am hoping to make the const reference method work (or even just reference because I don't NEED them to be constant) but I am unsure how to accomplish this.

Any help or direction on how to accomplish passing around parent Event objects is appreciated.

Comment: The solution is virtually always to not pass around pointers or references to base classes that don't have the methods you need.

Comment: @MooingDuck how come? I see why references but with pointers i can statically cast and get the methods i need.. its not too late to change how I pass around things but I need the parent class to be passed around because I never know what kind of event is getting thrown up. How should i pass these events?

Comment: You can statically cast references just like you do pointers.  `const MouseMovedEvent& childEvent = static_cast<const MouseMovedEvent&>(e);`  But it's not recommended. You almost always want to pass around objects that have methods you can call without casting.

Comment: @MooingDuck const references can be casted to children?

Comment: @Luke It's a sign of bad code design if you pass around a base class, but need to convert them to the correct child class to be able to use them.

Comment: Yes, const references can be cast to children exactly like pointers to const.  Though in both cases you almost certainly want `dynamic_cast`. But again: I've been a professional programmer for 10+ years, and only used `dynamic_cast` like three times.

Comment: So how should I approach something like this? I have mouse events, key events, etc and they all share code. How could I possibly avoid passing around the parent?

Comment: @Luke: `Event->dispatch()` fires itself as a `MouseMovedEvent` into your `MouseMovedEventHandler`.

Comment: You could use the visitor pattern, or you could make sure that the base class has virtual functions that works for all you child-classes to name a couple of ways.

Comment: @MooingDuck You have been super insightful. Please post the info you shared as an answer as this is exactly how i should be doing this. I need to create a dispatcher per event. Thank you so much you answered much more than you know you did. @ super I like the idea of that but key events couldnt possibly share methods with mousePosition events because things like getX() make no sense for key strokes.

Comment: Note: You're only allowed to cast like you do if you **know for certain** it is truly a pointer to that type--as opposed to a pointer to some other derived type. Otherwise, you're playing with undefined behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer the direct question: you can cast a reference exactly like you cast a pointer.

```
const MouseMovedEvent& childEvent = static_cast<const MouseMovedEvent&>(e);
```

However, when casting from a parent to a child, you almost always want to prefer `dynamic_cast`. Be aware that if the cast is wrong, `dynamic_cast` will throw a `std::bad_cast` exception, (which is a good thing, because otherwise it just causes your program to start doing completely undefined "random" things)

It's also worth noting that you *should not do this*.  You should always be interacting with classes that have the methods you need to interact with them. If you need to cast to a child, it's almost certain that you've designed this in an awkward way, and that there's a much cleaner design. Since you've clarified that you're working with Events, the solution is often something like a `Event->dispatch()`, which fires itself as a `MouseMovedEvent` into your `MouseMovedEventHandler`.

Comment: Also worth noting it that this is only possible if you know for sure it is an object of that type and not some other derived type. Otherwise, that's undefined behavior if I'm not mistaken.